# Unable to Create function

Tags: mysql

i have this code for mysql procedure but i am not able create procedure

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE hrpayroll.sal_gen_init
(IN `emp_id` INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE branch_cd varchar(20)
    DECLARE comp_cd varchar(20)
    SELECT p.BRANCH_CD IN branch_cd,p.COMP_CD IN comp_cd FROM p_employee_mst p WHERE p.EMPL_ID = emp_id
    INSERT INTO p_sal_hdr (COMP_CD,BRANCH_CD,EMPL_ID) VALUES(comp_cd,branch_cd,emp_id)
END @@ 
DELIMITER ;
```

i am getting this error

**Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE comp_cd varchar(20)
    SELECT p.BRANCH_CD IN branch_cd,p.COMP_CD IN com' at line 5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some syntax errors. Try this procedure -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sal_gen_ini(IN `emp_id` INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE branch_cd_var varchar(20);
  DECLARE comp_cd_var varchar(20);

  SELECT
    p.BRANCH_CD, p.COMP_CD INTO branch_cd_var, comp_cd_var
  FROM
    p_employee_mst p
  WHERE
    p.EMPL_ID = emp_id;

  INSERT INTO p_sal_hdr (COMP_CD,BRANCH_CD,EMPL_ID)
    VALUES(comp_cd_var,branch_cd_var,emp_id);
END
```

Note, that I also renamed declared variables to avoid problems with field and variable values.

---

Try to use one [SELECT...INTO Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into-statement.html) instead of two SELECT and INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

use `;`(semicolon) after the declare statement. ex,

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE branch_cd varchar(20);
    DECLARE comp_cd varchar(20);
```